# line by line comparison in unix

Tags: unix

There are 2 unix files. I want to compare the lines in file 1 to file 2 and if line in file 1 matches with file 2 print success else print failure. I have to do this in UNIX.

```
12,ADW
66,AIMS
3,CCA
85,CCDB
3,GXS
1,MDM
4,medsapecc
262,MIF
434,PI_CHARGEBACK
4,Pomniture
2,PSCORE
1,SDW
1,SNT Tables
5,VAPS
```

Second file:

```
12,ADW
25,AIMS
3,CCA
70,CCDB
3,CHARGEBACK
2,DISTRACK
5,GENESYS
3,GXS
20,MDM
14,MDSI
2,MEDIGXS
10,MEDSAPECC
267,MIF
15,P4
2,PEDMDB
2,PNSS
2,POMNITURE
3,PSCORE
20,SDW
5,VAPS
```

output file should be :

```
ADW SUCCESS
AIMS FAIL
CCA SUCCESS
CCDB FAIL
GXS SUCCESS
MDM FAIL
```

..etc .. please help ?

Comment: You should post the code you wrote to solve this problem and explain what exactly didn't work about it.

Comment: UNIX is a specification. Linux (well, technically GNU/Linux), OSX, BSD (FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD), etc are implementations of the specification. When you say you must do this in UNIX, that doesn't mean much. You can use one of the popular shell scripting languages like bash, zsh, sh, csh, etc. You can use Perl, Ruby, Python, etc. -- In which language are you trying to accomplish your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{arr[$2]=$1;next}
    {print $2, (arr[$2] == $1) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL"}
' FS=, file1 file2
```